# dacpac: how to control data among versions

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-data-tools, dacpac

I am trying to convert the sql server versioning from scripting-based to DACPAC. It works well with schema only. I has few issues once the data involved:

- For each version, we have 02 scripts (upgrade and restore) which can promote/downgrade the schema/data conversion to to next/previous version.
- DACPAC can help me to generate the delta between the current schema in DACPAC against the one in comparing database.

How to organize the scripts for upgrading or downgrading the data from 1 version to another version?

Thanks,

Comment: I guess you could put logic in the post-deploy script that does this. It's unusual to require downgrade scripts. How are these used?

Comment: CUrrently i am adding logic pre-deploy script and post-deploy script to upgrade from current version to next version. For example ver1: pre1, post1; ver2: pre2, post2; ... ver n where prei, posti are scripts to run from ver i to ver i+1. My problem is how to deploy from ver i to to ver n using dacpac?

Comment: You could just include all of your change scripts in your post-deploy script and let them run in order. SSDT will make your DB look like whatever your current dacpac looks like, schema-wise. You'll handle data modifications in your pre/post scripts.  As David noted, downgrades/rollbacks tend to be a bit more rare. You can always create those scripts in the project, but not add them to your pre/post deploy.  Also, you can create snapshots of your project and run through those one at a time if you want.